# Limit Android Filesize

Tags: java, android

**Background**

I'm keeping a relatively large text file in android storage, and appending to it periodically- while limiting the file's size to some arbitrary size (say 2MB)

Hopefully I'm missing a function somewhere, or hopefully there is a better way to do this process.

Currently, when the file `a` goes over that arbitrary size, I create a temporary file `b`, copy the relevant portion of the file `a` (more or less the substring of the file `a` starting at byte xxx where xxx is the number of bytes too large the file `a` would be if I wrote the next bit of data to the log) plus the current data, then overwrite the file `a` with the second file `b`.

This is obviously terribly inefficient...

Another solution that I'm not terribly fond of is to keep two files, and toggle between the two of them, clearing the next when the current is full, and switching to that file for output.

However, it would be suuuuuper handy if I could just do something like this

```
File A = new File("output");
A.chip(500);
```

or maybe

```
A.subfile(500,A.length()-500);
```

**TLDR;**

Is there a function or perhaps library available for Android that can remove a portion of a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you already take a look at [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)? Though you cannot remove portions of a file you can seek any position within the file and even set the length. So if you detect your file grows too large, just grab the relevant portion and jump to the beginning. Set length to 0 and write the new data.

EDIT:

I wrote a small demo. It shows if the file size is limeted to 10 bytes. If you pass in the values 10 to 15 as strings and separate them with commas, after 10,11,12, the file is written from the beginning, so after 15 it reads 13,14,15

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
  private static final long MAX = 10;
  private static final String FILE_TXT = "file.txt";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    for (int i = 10; i <= 15; i++) {
      if (i > 10) {
        writeToFile(",");
      }
      writeToFile(Integer.toString(i));
    }
  }

  private void writeToFile(String text) {
    try {
      File f = new File(getFilesDir(), FILE_TXT);
      RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
      long currentLength = file.length();
      if (currentLength + text.length() > MAX) {
        file.setLength(0);
      }
      file.seek(file.length());
      file.write(text.getBytes());
      file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "writeToFile()", e);
    }
    printFileContents();
  }

  private void printFileContents() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
      FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(FILE_TXT);
      int ch;
      while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) ch);
      }
      fin.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "printFileContents()", e);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "current content: " + sb.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to store the position of the current end/start in the file somehow, though.

Comment: Aha! I definitely did miss the RandomAccessFile class- that helps! I've implemented the toggling method plus this method and it works great! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you. Glad I was able to help.